# Post map course to Facebook using ShareOpenGraphObject

Tags: android, facebook

I'm creating an application that needs to post a run to Facebook using the [sharing view and open graph stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#advanced).
It posts the basic info like time and distance just fine, but for some reason i can't get the course to show on a map, like in this example:

[image]

This is the code i have to create the post:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataPoints.size(); i++) {
        DataPoint dataPoint = dataPoints.get(i);
        ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder metric = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder();
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:latitude", dataPoint.latitude);
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:longitude", dataPoint.longitude);
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:altitude", dataPoint.altitude);
        locations.add(metric.build());
    }

    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("fb:app_id", parent.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id))
            .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
            .putString("og:title", "Workout on " + date)
            .putString("og:url", BASE_URL + getApp().getUserName() + "/activity/" + summary.Id)
            .putInt("fitness:duration:value", summary.TijdInSecondes)
            .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
            .putDouble("fitness:distance:value", samenvatting.AfstandInMeters / 1000f)
            .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
            .putInt("fitness:speed:value", samenvatting.AfstandInMeters / samenvatting.TimeInSeconds)
            .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
            .putInt("fitness:calories", samenvatting.Kcal)
            .putObjectArrayList("fitness:metrics:location", locations)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("fitness.runs")
            .putObject("fitness:course", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
```

I also tried to encode the metrics to contain array indexes as described on [this bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1444106165910032):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataPoints.size(); i++) {
        DataPoint dataPoint = dataPoints.get(i);
        ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder metric = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder();
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:latitude", dataPoint.latitude);
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:longitude", dataPoint.longitude);
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:altitude", dataPoint.altitude);
        locations.add(metric.build());
    }
```

But that didn't fix it either. What am i missing?

Comment: @CBroe thanks, but i figured it out. It's just very unclear in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a lot simpler than expected. Instead of creating a seperate array for the locations, just add them to the original ShareOpenGraphObject directly but code the array numbers manually.

```
        ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("fb:app_id", parent.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id))
            .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
            .putString("og:title", "Workout on " + date)
            .putString("og:url", BASE_URL + getApp().getUserName() + "/activity/" + samenvatting.Id)
            .putInt("fitness:duration:value", samenvatting.TijdInSecondes)
            .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
            .putDouble("fitness:distance:value", samenvatting.AfstandInMeters / 1000f)
            .putString("fitness:distance:units", getApp().getSettings().speedUnitIsMetric() ? "km" : "mi")
            .putInt("fitness:speed:value", samenvatting.AfstandInMeters / samenvatting.TijdInSecondes)
            .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
            .putInt("fitness:calories", samenvatting.Kcal);


    for (int i = 0; i < dataPoints.size(); i++) {
        DataPoint dataPoint = dataPoints.get(i);
        object.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:latitude", dataPoint.latitude);
        object.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:longitude", dataPoint.longitude);
        object.putDouble("fitness:metrics[" + i + "]:location:altitude", dataPoint.altitude);
    }
```